# How to get the 1st element of List which is itself a member of Map of type Map[int, Any]

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, casting

Example:

```
var a = Map(1 -> List(7,8,9), 2 -> 15)
```

The type of variable a is `scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Any]`.

I want to get the 1st element of the `List(7, 8, 9)`.
`a(1)(0)` gives me an error : `Any does not take parameters`.

How can I typecast `Any` into `List`?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to @EndeNeu yet covering the case of empty lists, where for well-defining the problem we assume value `0`,

```
a.collect {
  case (i, Nil)   => (i, 0)
  case (i, x::_) => (i, x)
  case p @ (_, _) => p
}
```

Note `@` binds the tuple to `p` so that in the partial mapping we need not replicate the entire tuple.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks elm.

Answer (score 2):

Using collect should work:

```
scala> var a = Map(1 -> List(7,8,9), 2 -> 15)
a: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Any] = Map(1 -> List(7, 8, 9), 2 -> 15)

scala>   
   |   a collect {
   |     case (i: Int, l: List[_]) if l.nonEmpty => (i, l.head)
   |     case  (i: Int, j: Int) => (i, j)
   |   }
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Any] = Map(1 -> 7, 2 -> 15)
```

But I'd warn you against getting a collection with an `Any` in it, you lost all the type safety and that collect could not fetch what you want because the match is not exhaustive, I would review my approach if I were you, maybe using two collections depending on your application logic.

Comment: for `l: List[_] ...`, why not just pattern match: `case (i: Int, x :: _) => (i, x)`? I definitely agree with @Ende - re-evaluate why you're using `Map[Int, Any]`.

Comment: Works also but I'd say my version is more readable, I suppose it's a subjective thing though.